# Pascal's Triangle in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm trying to write a function of the type:

```
pascal : int * int -> int
```

where the pair of ints represent the row and column, respectively, of Pascal's triangle.

Here's my attempt:

```
fun pascal(i : int, j : int) : int =
    if (i = 0 andalso j = 0) orelse i = j orelse i = 0
        then 1
    else
        pascal(i - 1, j - 1) + pascal(i - 1, j);
```

It works for my base cases but gives me strange output otherwise.  For instance:

`pascal(4, 2)` gives me 11 and `pascal(4, 1)` gives me 15

It's a bit strange because, as long as the if clause fails and the else gets evaluated, I do want to return the sum of the element one row above and the element one row above and one element to the left.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have to write "Thanks", or sign with your name, since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `pascal 1 0`. If you're using zero-based indexing for the table then this should be equal to 1. But:

```
pascal 1 0 = pascal 0 -1 + pascal 0 0 = 2
```

You should put some guards to deal with negative indices and indices where `j` is greater than `i`.

Comment: OK, great I just fixed the negative indices issue by basically saying "if you get i or j < 0, then give back 0".  I don't see how this was causing me to get 11 and 15 for the calls listed in my post tho.  Also, assuming the user doesn't input j > i, I don't think my code can reach that.  That would require i = j and that returns 1 and makes no further recursive calls.

Comment: @bclayman You're right about it not being possible to reach  j > i if the user doesn't input them. I was thinking about the interpretation in terms of binomial coefficients. Did fixing the issue with the negative indexes get the right result?

Comment: Ahh gotcha.  It did, but I'm not sure why it would give me 11 or 15 for the calls I mention in OP.  I understand high-level it shouldn't make calls with negative indices but past that I'm a bit lost about how the value is overshooting its correct value (e.g. 11 instead of 6).

Comment: Well, when you bottom out at the recursion on the left side you'll always overshoot by one. These overshoots add up.